# Не обрабатывается action после перехода с Apache на Nginx MVC PHP

Tags: php, nginx, mvc

При переходе с Apache на Nginx перестал отрабатываться экшен.

```html
<form method="post" action="DeleteUserById" class="form-signin" id="form-reg" name="form-reg">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="DeleteUserById">
    Id: <input type="text" name="Id" class="form-control" id="Id" placeholder="Идентификатор" required>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" value="Удалить"/>
</form>
```

Controller с методом

```php
<?php

namespace controllers;

use models\UsersModel;
use views\View;

class UsersController extends Controller
{

    private $pageTpl = "/views/users.tpl.php";

    public function __construct() {
        $this->model = new UsersModel();
        $this->view = new View();
    }

    public function index() 
    {

        if(!$_SESSION['user'])
        {
            header("Location: /");
            exit();
        }

        $this->pageData['permission'] = $_SESSION['role_id'];

        $this->pageData['title'] = "Пользователи";
        $this->pageData['usersList'] = $this->model->getUsers();


        $this->view->render($this->pageTpl, $this->pageData);
    }

    # Удаление сотрудника
    public function DeleteUserById()
    {
        $id= $_POST ["Id"];
        $this->model->deleteUser($id);
        $this->pageData['registerMsg'] = "Сотрудник удален из системы";
        header("Location: users");
        return true;
    }

}
```

Nginx-1.11_vhost.conf

```
#-----------------------------------------------#
# Начало блока конфигурации хоста
#-----------------------------------------------#

server {
    listen                    %ip%:%httpport%;
    listen                    %ip%:%httpsport% ssl http2;
    server_name               %host% %aliases%;
    root                      "%hostdir%";
    index                     index.php index.html index.htm;
    autoindex                 on;  # Выводить листинг каталога если не найден индексный файл
    limit_conn                perip 64; # Ограничение кол-ва соединений с одного IP

    # Создание сертификатов на примере файлов от COMODO
    # copy /b domain.crt+COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt+COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt server.crt
    # copy /b COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt+COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt trusted.crt
    # openssl.exe dhparam -out dhparam.pem 2048

    ssl_certificate           "%sprogdir%/userdata/config/cert_files/server.crt";
    ssl_certificate_key       "%sprogdir%/userdata/config/cert_files/server.key";
    ssl_dhparam               "%sprogdir%/userdata/config/cert_files/dhparam.pem";
    # ssl_trusted_certificate "%sprogdir%/userdata/config/cert_files/trusted.crt";

    # Отсекаем известных ботов (список можно дополнить через разделитель "|")
    if ($http_user_agent ~* (MJ12bot|Solomono|Ahrefs|SISTRIX|LinkpadBot|nmap|nikto|wikto|sqlmap|bsqlbf|w3af|acunetix|havij|appscan)) {
        return 444;
    }

    # Запрещаем чтение скрытых файлов (начинающихся с точки)
    # Доступ к каталогам /.well/ и /.known/ будет разрешён (список можно дополнить через разделитель "|")
    location ~* /\.(?!(well|known)\/) {
        deny all;
    }
    
      charset utf-8;
  
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @php;
    }
      
    location @php {
        rewrite ^/(.*) /index.php?url=$1;
    }

    # Запрещаем браузерам самим определять тип документа (определяет сервер)
    more_set_headers "X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff";

    # Включаем Content-Security-Policy (разрешения: +Google Аnalytics +Google Fonts +Яндекс Метрика)
    # more_set_headers "Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://ssl.google-analytics.com https://mc.yandex.ru https://yastatic.net; img-src 'self' https://ssl.google-analytics.com https://mc.yandex.ru; connect-src https://mc.yandex.ru; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://fonts.googleapis.com; font-src 'self' https://themes.googleusercontent.com; frame-src 'self'; object-src 'none'";

    # Ограничиваем методы обращения к серверу (список можно дополнить через разделитель "|")
    # if ($request_method !~* ^(GET|HEAD|POST)$){return 405;}

    # NEW! Ограничиваем скорость независимо от числа соединений
    # limit_traffic_rate rate_ip 1024k; # Ограничиваем скорость по IP адресу
    # limit_traffic_rate rate_uri 1024k; # Ограничиваем скорость по URL адресу

    # Принудительное использование HTTPS на сайте
    # more_set_headers "Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15768000";
    # more_set_headers "Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15768000; includeSubdomains;"; # (включая поддомены)
    # set $do_redirect  1;
    # if ($scheme ~* ^https$) {
    #     set $do_redirect 0;
    # }
    # if ($request_uri ~* ^/robots\.txt$) {
    #     set $do_redirect 0;
    # }
    # if ($do_redirect = 1) {
    #     return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    # }

    # Запрет использования www префикса (www.xxx.com => xxx.com)
    # if ($host ~* ^www\.(.+)$) {
    #     set $host_without_www $1;
    #     return 301 $scheme://$1$request_uri;
    # }

    # Перенаправление абсолютно всех запросов к PHP обработчику
    # location / {
    #     rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php last;
    # }

    # Перенаправление всех запросов к PHP обработчику
    # (если такой файл или папка не существуют)
    # location / {
    #     try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    # }

    # Запрещаем доступ к конфигам/бэкапам/логам (список можно дополнить через разделитель "|")
    # location ~* ^.+\.(bak|conf|log|ini|sql|tar|tgz|gz)$ {
    #     deny all; 
    # }

    location ~* ^.+\.(css|htc|js|bmp|gif|jpe?g|tiff?|png|cur|ico|woff2?|eot|ttc|ttf|otf|svg|swf)$ {
        expires 1d; # Кэшируем статическое содержимое
        # Разрешаем кросс-доменные запросы
        # more_set_headers "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *";
    }

    location ~* ^.+\.php$ {
        limit_conn perip 32; # Ограничение кол-ва соединений с одного IP
        limit_req zone=dynamic burst=32 nodelay; # Ограничение частоты запросов к PHP
        more_set_headers "X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN"; # Запрещаем фреймы на чужих сайтах
        # more_set_headers "Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, no-transform"; # Запрещаем кэширование ответов
        try_files                         $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass                      backend;
        fastcgi_param  TMP                "%sprogdir%/userdata/temp";
        fastcgi_param  TMPDIR             "%sprogdir%/userdata/temp";
        fastcgi_param  TEMP               "%sprogdir%/userdata/temp";
        include                           "%sprogdir%/modules/http/%httpdriver%/conf/fastcgi_params";
    }

    #-----------------------------------------------#
    # Подключение веб-инструментов
    # Не изменяйте этот блок конфигурации
    #-----------------------------------------------#

    location /openserver/ {
        root            "%sprogdir%/modules/system/html";
        index           index.php;

        %allow%allow    all;
        allow           127.0.0.0/8;
        allow           ::1/128;
        allow           %ips%;
        deny            all;

        location /openserver/server-status {
            stub_status on;
            access_log  off;
        }

        location ~* ^.+\.(css|htc|js|bmp|gif|jpe?g|tiff?|png|cur|ico|woff2?|eot|ttc|ttf|otf|svg|swf)$ {
            expires 1d; # Кэшируем статическое содержимое
        }

        location ~* ^/openserver/.+\.php$ {
            limit_conn perip 32; # Ограничение кол-ва соединений с одного IP
            limit_req zone=dynamic burst=32 nodelay; # Ограничение частоты запросов к PHP
            more_set_headers "X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN"; # Запрещаем фреймы на чужих сайтах
            # more_set_headers "Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, no-transform"; # Запрещаем кэширование ответов
            try_files                         $uri =404;
            fastcgi_pass                      backend;
            fastcgi_param  TMP                "%sprogdir%/userdata/temp";
            fastcgi_param  TMPDIR             "%sprogdir%/userdata/temp";
            fastcgi_param  TEMP               "%sprogdir%/userdata/temp";
            include                           "%sprogdir%/modules/http/%httpdriver%/conf/fastcgi_params";
        }
    }

    #-----------------------------------------------#
    # Конфигурация сообщений об ошибках
    #-----------------------------------------------#

    error_page 500 /500.html;
    error_page 501 /501.html;
    error_page 502 504 /502.html;
    error_page 503 /503.html;
    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 405 /405.html;

    location ~* ^/(500|501|502|503|404|405).html$ {
        root             "%sprogdir%/userdata/config/error_pages";
        expires          -1;
        more_set_headers "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8";
        internal;
    }
}

#-----------------------------------------------#
# Конец блока конфигурации хоста
#-----------------------------------------------#
```

Что не так? Пожалуйста, объясните

Comment: конфиг джинкса в студию

Comment: Прикрепил к посту

Comment: Какой в документе получается базовый URL? По коду видно только относительный URL на `DeleteUserById`. Не понятно куда это должно вести, не имея базового URL. Проще говоря: как выглядит адрес, по которому отправляется форма, целиком?

Comment: http://localhost/cabinet/users/